# output of multiprocessing info

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to learn more about multiprocessing with Python. I am using the `multiprocessing` module but I cannot understand how it work. 
these are the function wrote to implement the multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import random

zones = []

for i in range(0,10):
    x = random.randint(1,10)
    zones.append(x)
def chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]
def info(title):
    print(title)
    print( 'module name:', __name__)
    if hasattr(os, 'getppid'):  # only available on Unix
        print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print( 'process id:', os.getpid())

def worker(x):

    for i in range(0,5):
        print( x * i)

def main():


    man = mp.Manager()
    split = chunks(zones, len(zones)//4)
    for z in split:
        info('==========')
        p = mp.Process(target=worker,args=(z,))
        print(p)
        p.start()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.set_start_method('fork')
    main()
```

I got this output on the shell

```
    ==========
module name: __main__
parent process: 5226
process id: 7774
<Process(Process-2, initial)>
==========
module name: __main__
parent process: 5226
process id: 7774
<Process(Process-3, initial)>
[]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
==========
module name: __main__
parent process: 5226
process id: 7774
<Process(Process-4, initial)>
[]
[5, 2]
[5, 2, 5, 2]
[5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 2]
[5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 2]
==========
module name: __main__
parent process: 5226
process id: 7774
<Process(Process-5, initial)>
==========
module name: __main__
parent process: 5226
process id: 7774
[]
<Process(Process-6, initial)>
[5, 3]
[5, 3, 5, 3]
[5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3]
[5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5, 3]
[]
[9, 10]
[9, 10, 9, 10]
[9, 10, 9, 10, 9, 10]
[9, 10, 9, 10, 9, 10, 9, 10]
[]
[1, 7]
[1, 7, 1, 7]
[1, 7, 1, 7, 1, 7]
[1, 7, 1, 7, 1, 7, 1, 7]
```

why the process if is always the same and it doesn't change? since I am splitting the processing on pieces I were expecting to have the code running on different process id.

Comment: "Copy the code from your question into a new file or project, then run it. If it doesn't run for you, then it won't run for anyone else." from [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Please modify your example according to this HOW-TO

Comment: You need to make the call to `info` from within `worker`. As it is now, you only ever call from the main process.

Comment: this is why I have always the same process id but the `<Process(Process-6, initial)>` changes?

Comment: In your current code change: `for z in split:
        info('==========')` into `for z in split:
        print '=========='` and `def worker(x):` into 
    `info("subprocess")
    for i in range(0,5):
        print( x * i)`

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: Yes!! I understood now!!! Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 2):

None of your workers call `info`. Try this:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

def info():
    print("==")
    print('module name:', __name__)
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

def worker(arg):
    info()
    print("worker arg: {}".format(arg, ))

man = mp.Manager()
for z in [1,2,3,4]:
    p = mp.Process(target=worker,args=(z,))
    p.start()
```

Output:

```
==
module name: __main__
parent process: 2253
process id: 2256
worker arg: 1
==
module name: __main__
parent process: 2253
process id: 2258
worker arg: 3
==
module name: __main__
parent process: 2253
process id: 2257
worker arg: 2
==
module name: __main__
parent process: 2253
process id: 2259
worker arg: 4
```

Comment: i tried this and it works but, since I have a loop inside a single, process I have the same `process id` inside the loop. the multiprocessing is made "running" those loop on the same time on different cores, and each one single loop still remain on one process right?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function `info` from the loop in the main and not in the children processes.

Adapt your code based on:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

def info(title):
  print(title)
  print('module name:', __name__)
  print('parent process:', os.getppid())
  print('process id:', os.getpid())

## Function chunks used to divide the input files into slices
zones=[1,2,3,4]
for z in zones:
  p = Process(target=info,args=(z,))
  p.start()
  p.join()
```

**Output:**

```
 python multiprocess.py
1
('module name:', '__main__')
('parent process:', 47974)
('process id:', 47975)
2
('module name:', '__main__')
('parent process:', 47974)
('process id:', 47976)
3
('module name:', '__main__')
('parent process:', 47974)
('process id:', 47977)
4
('module name:', '__main__')
('parent process:', 47974)
('process id:', 47978)
```

Comment: Now the child process *is* `info`. There is no calling anymore. Maybe this is a little bit too concise.

Comment: @LutzHorn: The OP is trying to create subprocesses of the process from the main and do some processing. In the subprocesses  he can call as many functions as he wants, I don't think this is the point anyway

Comment: @GloriP.: exactly you can just rename it info in worker in my code and it should work. What you did wrong is that you are calling your `info` method directly in the loop that creates the subprocesses. You need to call it within the subprocesses to have different PIDs.